# Windows restore points - The meaning of RestorePointType

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi

The API function [CreateRestorePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378847(v=vs.85).aspx) creates a restore point. The method takes one of the following values as the **RestorePointType**:

- APPLICATION_INSTALL
- APPLICATION_UNINSTALL
- DEVICE_DRIVER_INSTALL
- MODIFY_SETTINGS

What is the difference and does it affect the list of files that are saved for the checkpoint?

I noticed when I manually created it using `Checkpoint-Computer` that PowerShell function uses `APPLICATION_INSTALL` by default; it didn't save all the files on Windows 10 Pro: some `~\Documents` weren't reverted later when I restored the checkpoint.

- [Checkpoint-Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/checkpoint-computer)
- [RestorePointType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.checkpointcomputercommand.restorepointtype(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Might be worth looking at the ServerFault and/or SuperUser stack exchanges, e.g: https://superuser.com/a/350427/543612. This answer states that user (profile) data is not included in a restore point.

Comment: I believe that the `RestorePointType` is informational to assist a user with choosing when they want to restore to. E.g If an application install caused a failure they would be able to identify appropriate the restore point based on that information.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt, that is very old answer, stuff changed several times in that land since then. AFAIK Volume Shadow Copy does a snapshot of entire drive which wasn't the case on previous versions of Windows

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

As [BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6788803/benh) mentioned in the comments, these are only informational, for description.

When an application calls the [SRSetRestorePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/SRRestorePtAPI/nf-srrestoreptapi-srsetrestorepointa) function, it can provide **any text as a description for the restore point**; however, the following table shows the recommended **description text**.

Installers, such as Windows Installer and InstallShield, use these conventions for the description text:

- The product name follows the verb; for example, Installed AppName.
- The product name can be used alone (AppName) or the product name and
- the company name may both be used (MyCompany AppName).

[image]

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sr/restore-point-description-text)